# Assembly : add two numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, nasm, mov

I would like to add two number num1B and num2B and store the number in result, finaly show result.

But, when i launch nasm, it says :

prog2_1.txt:4: warning: attempt to initialize memory in a nobits section: ignored

prog2_1.txt:5: warning: attempt to initialize memory in a nobits section: ignored

prog2_1.txt:6: warning: attempt to initialize memory in a nobits section: ignored

my code :

```
org 0x0100 ;

section .bss
    num1B: db 0Ah ; init num1B to 0Ah
    num2B: db 00111111b ; init num2B to 00111111b
    result: db 0 ; init result to 0

section .data

section .text

    mov AX,0 ; AX = 0
    add AX,[num1B] ; AX = AX + num1B
    add AX,[num2B] ; AX = AX + num2B
    mov [result],AX ; result = result + AX

    mov DX,[result] ; show result
    mov AH,09h
    int 21h

    mov AH,4Ch
    int 21h
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your `.bss` section to `.data` section. The `.bss` section is meant for uninitialized data, while the `.data` section is meant for initialized data. That's why you can't use `db`, `dw` and so forth in `.bss` section. Instead, you can place them in `.data` section. Similarly, you can use `resb`. `resw` and so forth in `.bss` section but not in `.data` section.

In short, `.data` is for initialized data and `.bss` is for uninitialized data.

Comment: Ok thanks for these good explanations :-) The 3 messages disappear but it's still not working :-(

Comment: How are you running this? Is anyone setting the `DS` register to the .data segment (hint!)?

Comment: With dosbox 0.74 but i've got lot of random symbols :-(

Comment: The "show string" function(mov ah, 09h, int 21h) expects a pointer to the string to be shown. You are supplying raw values to the function, which interprets them as a pointer and as such does not show what you expect it to show. You need to create a few byte string buffer(just allocate enough bytes with RESB(put in .bss) for example), then set the result of the addition to that buffer, place dollar-sign($, 24h in hex) at the end of the string(in DOS, dollar-sign terminates a string) and set DS:DX to be the address of the first byte of that buffer before you call the "show string" function.

Comment: I tried something @zxcdw : http://ideone.com/ipIxe

So i have created a string, and i tried to put the result in it (doesn't work), then i should concatenate a '$' at the end.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, 
prog2_1.txt:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: Instead of `add`ing the $ to the value, you need to append it at the end of the string. The string should consist of bytes between 0x30 and 0x39 because those are the ASCII symbols representing the decimals from 0 to 9. The length of the string should be at least the amount of decimal numbers in your result +1. If the result of addition is 16, then the string should be at least 3 bytes in length(because value 16 is 2 symbols and the string ends in '$'.) So what you need to do now is to convert from arbitrary byte value to ASCII string. From f.e. value 127(in dec) to bytes 0x31,0x32,0x37 + '$'

Comment: It's a very long way. Is there something easier to add two number and just show the result Oo

Comment: No!  Using Assembly is like you wanting to drive your car, but first you have to build it first.  With Assembly, you have to program each and every thing you want the CPU to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's a long road. If you want "easy", stick to BASIC! You're making progress. You've got your two numbers in ".data", not ".bss", but I assume they're still "db". When you use ax for the addition, it uses 16 bits - a "word" or two bytes. This puts one number in al and the second number in ah - not what you want! Either use al for the addition, or make your two numbers (and the result!) "dw" rather than "db". "Display the result" is the hard part, and doing words is probably easier than bytes, besides letting you display numbers bigger than 255. Someone has just posted a "display the result" routine... as a macro for Masm, but you should be able to modify the code to work in Nasm. You probably don't want a macro - it'll duplicate the same code every time you use it. A subroutine would be better, but if you don't know how to do that just put it "in line" - you're only doing it once (for now). If you continue to have trouble, post some more recent code...

Best,
Frank
http://www.nasm.us